# ERROR: Error 1366: Incorrect integer value: 'ID_1' for column 'ID' at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Auction`.`Card_company` (
  `ID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Card No.` INT NOT NULL,
  `Company name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `expiration date(YYDD)` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`),
  CONSTRAINT `owner_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ID`)
    REFERENCES `Auction`.`buyer_ID` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Above is my dml query and below is insert query.

```
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_1', 111111, '신한', '2001');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_2', 111113, '신한', '2002');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_4', 111115, '신한', '2003');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_4', 111116, '신한', '2004');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_5', 111117, '신한', '2005');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_6', 111118, '신한', '2006');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_7', 111119, '비씨', '2007');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_8', 111120, '비씨', '2008');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_9', 111121, '비씨', '2009');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_10', 111122, '비씨', '2010');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_11', 111123, '비씨', '2011');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_12', 111124, '롯데', '2012');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_13', 111125, '롯데', '2001');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_14', 111127, '롯데', '2002');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_15', 111128, '롯데', '2004');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_16', 111129, '롯데', '2006');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_17', 111130, '롯데', '2008');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_18', 111131, '현대', '2009');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_19', 111132, '현대', '2012');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_20', 111133, '현대', '2010');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_21', 111134, '현대', '2003');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_22', 111135, '현대', '2001');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_24', 111137, '삼성', '2005');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_24', 111139, '삼성', '2004');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_25', 111140, '삼성', '2007');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_26', 111141, '삼성', '2008');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_27', 111142, '삼성', '2010');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_28', 111143, '우리', '2009');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_29', 111144, '우리', '2011');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_1', 111112, '우리', '2010');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_3', 111114, '우리', '2005');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_13', 111126, '우리', '2006');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_23', 111136, '국민', '2008');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_23', 111138, '국민', '2003');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_30', 111139, '국민', '2004');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_31', 111140, '국민', '2010');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_32', 111141, '국민', '2011');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_33', 111142, '농협', '2012');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_34', 111143, '농협', '2008');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES ('ID_35', 111145, '농협', '2004');
INSERT INTO `Auction`.`Card_company` (`ID`, `Card No.`, `Company name`, `expiration date(YYDD)`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, '', NULL);
```

When I forward engineer to data, Error 1366 was occurred.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I removed the sql-server tag because the syntax is MySQL.

Comment: I would guess that the problem is the last line that is trying to insert `NULL` into a `NOT NULL` column.

Comment: What data type is `Auction.buyer_ID`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: That would naturally cause an error, but I don't think that it gets that far. The error message suggests that it stops already on the first insert.

Comment: @Guffa It is varchar(45)

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Error explicitly states there's a problem with unexpected integer value "ID_1", which probably means it fails during the first insert. So I would agree with Guffa, there looks to be a problem that ID field is referencing INT field, could this be?

Comment: Have you checked that the table doesn't already exist, with different data types?

Comment: @AndreySereda Unfortunately ID field does not be referencing INT FIELD;;

Comment: Could you also give the definition of the table `Auction`.`buyer_ID`? Also, will mysql accept it when you try to insert only the year into a date column?

Comment: @JodyT Here is buyer_iD



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Auction`.`buyer_ID` (
  `ID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `payment` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`, `payment`),
  CONSTRAINT `company_name`
    FOREIGN KEY (`payment`)
    REFERENCES `Auction`.`Card_company` (`Company name`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

Comment: What happens if you try to insert just the first row? Could you change the date from `2001` to `20010101` and try that single row again.

Comment: @JodyT I tried your request, but it is same, it means same error code occurs when I insert first row and change the 2001 to 20010101